# SICP - exercise 1.12 - pascal's triangle

Tags: performance, comparative-review, lisp, scheme, sicp

From SICP:

> Exercise 1.12: The following pattern of numbers is called Pascal’s triangle.
>
> 1
>        1   1
>      1   2   1
>    1   3   3   1
>  1   4   6   4   1
>        . . .
>
> The numbers at the edge of the triangle are all 1, and each number inside the triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it. Write a procedure that computes elements of Pascal’s triangle by means of a recursive process.

Here is my code:

```
(define (pascals-triangle row col)
  ;; "The numbers at the edge of the triangle are all 1"
  (if (or (= col 0) (= col row))
      1
      (+ (pascals-triangle (- row 1)
                            (- col 1))
          (pascals-triangle (- row 1)
                            col))))
```

I noticed that the edges of the triangle after 1 is (probably) always the number of rows, because we always add 1 to them when we go to the next row. So I rewrote the code with a minor change.

```
(define (pascals-triangle row col)
  (cond ((or (= col 0) (= col row))
         1)
        ((or (= col 1) (= col (- row 1)))
         row)
      (else (+ (pascals-triangle (- row 1)
                                  (- col 1))
                (pascals-triangle (- row 1)
                                  col)))))
```

In my previous code, if the colum is 0, the running time is constant. Now in the revised code, it's also constant if the column is 1. And since this is recursive, I am guessing I saved a few steps. Will making small changes like that have a significant impact with my code and systems a lot larger than this?

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should memoise the recursive call in order to make it faster. Since each value has a computational sibling (its value is derived from (one or two) parents which also each has another child), you remove the double-computation that would occur.

Additionally, these double-computations would actually accumulate exponentially up the levels, so it's no longer just a micro-optimisation; it actually affects the your runtime complexity. So it's even more important to implement memoisation.